# File upload with Dropbox .NET SDK doesn't finish

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

The files created on my dropbox account are only like 80-90 bytes instead of the full size of 3-5 mb.

Upload function:

```
async Task Upload(DropboxClient dbx, string folder, string file, string content)
    {
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)))
        {
            var updated = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(
                folder + "/" + file,
                WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance,
                body: mem);
            //Console.WriteLine("Saved {0}/{1} rev {2}", folder, file, updated.Rev);
        }
    }
```

Where I call the function:

```
var t = Task.Run(() => Upload(new DropboxClient("mykey"), "/TargetFolder", FileName, FileLocalLocation));
        t.Wait();
```

Comment: What is `FileLocalLocation`?

Comment: The path to the file I want to upload on my local machine. Edit: the files uploaded just contain a string of the location on my PC instead of the actual bytes from the file.

Comment: If you read your code, you will certainly understand what you are doing: you are creating text files into Dropbox containing only a path. You are not uploading anything.

Comment: Changed Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes() to File.ReadAllBytes() and it works now. Sorry for the dumb question and thanks for the assistance